# How to fix my Bookmark local-storage service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Bookmark Service which stores a result item with JSON structure doesn't work well.
Probably the issue comes from the array that doesn't work with the local storage function.

I've tried to JSON.stringify my items.

```
    var key = 'fud_bookmarks';
    var bookmarks = [];

    this.addBookmark = function(resultItem) {
      var bookmarks = this.getBookmarks();
      bookmarks.push(resultItem);
      return setBookmarks(bookmarks);
    };

    this.deleteBookmark = function(resultItem) {
      var bookmarks = this.getBookmarks();
      var i = bookmarks.indexOf(resultItem);
      if (i >= 0) {
        bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(bookmarks)
        return setBookmarks(bookmarks);
      }
      return false;
    };

    this.getBookmarkCount = function() {
      return getBookmarks().length;
    };

    this.getBookmarks = function() {
      var bookmarks = localStorage.getItem(key);

      if (!bookmarks) {
        bookmarks = [];
      }

      return bookmarks;
    }


    function setBookmarks(bookmarks) {
      return localStorage.setItem(key, bookmarks);
    }
```

The resulted items look like this.

```
    {
      id: "112",
      docType: "doctyp117",
      title: "Abschließender Bericht über die Arbeit des Kunsts…- September 1944, Exemplar für Tieschowitz, o.D.",
      type: "Archivbestand",
      description: null,
      …
    }

    $$hashKey: "object:455"

    archive: {
      id: "24",
      title: "Familienarchiv der Grafen Wolff Metternich zur Gracht"
    }
```

right now I get this error in the console =>

```
bookmarks.push is not a function
    at Object.addBookmark (bookmark.js:12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localStorage store a string values, not an objects. 
If you want to store an Array should stringify it.

```
function setBookmarks(bookmarks) {
   return localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
}
```

```
this.getBookmarks = function () {
  var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
...
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

If value in starage will be not a valid JSON `JSON.parse` method throw an error, so you can use a try catch to avoid errors:

```
this.getBookmarks = function () {
  var bookmarks;

  try {
    bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
  } catch (e) {
    bookmarks = [];
  }
...
```

deleteBookmark should looks like:

```
this.deleteBookmark = function (resultItem) {
  var i = 0;

  let bookmarks = this.getBookmarks();
​
  for (;i < bookmarks.length - 1;i++) {
    if (resultItem.id === bookmarks[i].id) {
      break;
    }
  }

 if (i >= 0) {
   bookmarks.splice(i, 1);
   console.log(bookmarks)
   return setBookmarks(bookmarks);
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is what iam looking for. Works great. Only my delete Bookmark function doesn't work. No error message, its just not working.

Comment: I think the problem in `var i = bookmarks.indexOf(resultItem);`, 
`indexOf` can`t search by object. You need to use `forEach` and find by `id` property

Comment: But i didn't need localstorage.removeItem. Right?

Comment: yes, you no need a `localstorage.removeItem`, I just updated my answer with updated `this.deleteBookmark`method

Comment: yeah we are getting closer. But now it deletes the complete bookmark array.

Comment: added `let bookmarks = this.getBookmarks();` to the this.deleteBookmark method, works for me

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:** Check if typeof bookmarks is not object then return empty array. As Array is also a special type of object in javascript.

```
this.getBookmarks = function() {
      var bookmarks = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (typeof bookmarks !== "object") {
        bookmarks = [];
      };

    return bookmarks;
    };
```

Comment: The Error is gone. Thanks!! But i didn't receive bookmarks in the getBookmarks function. The bookmarks must be saved in the localStorage.